# PHP - Loop checkboxes and save it to the database

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter, checkbox

I am having a challenge in PHP and HTML check boxes. Would you help me with this?

Here is my scenario:

I have a User Role module where you will create a user role and then assign what modules that role can access using check boxes. I will attach a screenshot.

What I want to do is to loop through that check box array, and then save each checkbox with a check on it.

Getting all the checked check boxes is fine. I have found a code for that.

Now, I checked a check box for example Delivery module, and then save it, of course it will go to the database. What if I edited the user role, and then unchecked the Delivery module, and saved it, should I delete that row? Because what I understand each checkbox will be saved as a row in the database.

That is the part that I can't imagine how to implement. Would you help me how is the design for that?

Hope I explained myself well. Please let me know if there are unclear parts. Thank you any suggestion, I appreciate it.

Here are some details Hope it would help:

I am using CodeIgniter and MS SQL Server as database.

Here is my code:

```html
          <?php if ($this->session->userdata('portalModules')):
            $portalModules = $this->session->userdata('portalModules');
            $prevGroup = NULL;
            $firstGroup = TRUE;
          ?>
          <?php foreach ($portalModules as $moduleGroup): ?>
            <?php if ($moduleGroup['moduleGroup'] !== $prevGroup): ?>
              <?php if (!$firstGroup): ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php else: ?>
              <?php $firstGroup = FALSE; ?>
              <?php endif ?>

              <?php $prevGroup = $moduleGroup['moduleGroup']; ?>
              <div>
                <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name=""><?php echo $moduleGroup['moduleGroup']; ?></div>
                <div>
                  <?php foreach ($portalModules as $menu): ?>
                    <?php if ($menu['moduleGroup'] == $moduleGroup['moduleGroup']): ?>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <p style="margin-left: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" name=""><?php echo $menu['moduleName']; ?></p>
                      
                     </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif ?>
            
          <?php endforeach ?>
```

[Here is the screenshot of check boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA5HK.png)

Comment: the nice thing to do when someone answers your question is to respond

Comment: @Alex, I apologize, however your answer gave me idea. So, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a table called permissions consisting of boolean columns or enum columns with options being 1,0 and default option being 0:

[image]

When the user is created simply add their id to the table and if you set the default to 0 you don't have to worry about handling nulls when you do role checks.

If an admin unchecks `delivery_detailed` checkbox then simply change the value from 1 to 0. No deleting rows. Easy.

```
   /**
     * Check to see if user is allowed for $cpermission
     * 
     * @param string $cpermission
     * @param int $uid User id
     * @return boolean
     */
    function check_user_role($cpermission, $uid) {
        $this->db->select($cpermission);
        $q = $this->db->get_where('user_roles', array('user_id' => $uid));
        if ($q->num_rows() !== 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return intval($q->row()->{$cpermission}) == 1; // is user allowed?
    }

    /**
     * Update a user role
     * 
     * @param string $cpermission
     * @param int $val ON/OFF 1,0
     * @param int $uid User id
     * @return boolean
     */
    function update_user_role($cpermission, $val, $uid) {
        $this->populate_user_roles($uid);
        $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);
        return $this->db->update('user_roles', array($cpermission => $val));
    }

    /**
     * Adds new user to user role table with all 0 permissions
     * 
     * @param int $uid
     * @return boolean
     */
    function populate_user_roles($uid) {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);
        // user doesn't exist in user role table yet??
        if ($this->db->count_all_results('user_roles') < 1) {
            $columns = $this->db->list_fields('user_roles'); // get all columns
            $data = array_fill_keys($columns, 0); // fill with 0
            unset($data['user_id']); // remove user_id (we don't want [user_id] => 0
            $data['user_id'] = $uid; // add proper user_id to $data array
            return $this->db->insert('user_roles', $data);
        } else {
            return true; // user exists in roles table
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi I am really sorry to get back this late. That is so rude. I am able to solve this problem using your given idea. But what I did is I don't create a column for each module since the module list is growing over time. I just save the module id and the user id to check if a user has permission to a module. During editing, I delete all the saved module id, and reinsert it again. Thankyou Alex.